# Jupyter Datascience docker - connecting to mssql server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pymssql

I'm trying to setup docker image from jupyter/datascience-notebook, on top of that I'm adding some libraries needed for my work.
Our database is MS SQL Server 17 running on ubuntu server. For connecting to MS SQL db server, I'm including following lines in Dockerfile.

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
RUN apt-get update
```

When I build the docker image, I don't see errors, but when I'm opening a connection, I'm getting following error

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

Code for opening connection:

```
self.cnxn_str = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + \
                self.ip + ';DATABASE=' + self.db + ';UID=' + self.uid + 
    ';PWD=' + self.pwd
    self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.cnxn_str)
```

Has anyone else managed to setup docker from which read/write operations happen on MS SQL Server 17? Kindly let me know what steps am I missing.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi,
Yes I managed to solve it. From what I recall, the problem was I didn't install odbc pips before apt-get install mssql. Try to include followig before install mssql step in your Dockerfile

RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
  unixodbc \
  unixodbc-dev \
  odbcinst 

let me know if it helps.